# Python: shapefile.Reader, how to set up .iloc?

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas, pyshp

I would like to set up range of reading by `shapefile.Reader`. I couldn't find any suitable documentation.
I would like to read rows 0-100. In Pandas or GeoPandas I use `df.iloc[0:100]`, but what should I use here?

Code:

```
with shapefile.Reader(shapefile_path) as shp:
    total_rows = shp.numRecords
    for row_num, row in enumerate(shp.iterRecords()):
        print(row)
```

Answer (score 10):

A generator is not subscriptable and `iterRecords()` returns a generator. Instead, use `shapeRecords()` (or `records()`). It gives you a list.

```
rows = shapefile.Reader(shapefile_path).shapeRecords()[0:100]

for row_num, row in enumerate(rows):
    print(row_num, row)
```

Answer (score 7):

I have found the solution:

```
with shapefile.Reader(shapefile_path) as shp:
        total_rows = shp.numRecords
        for row_num, row in enumerate(shp.iterRecords()):
            if row_num < 0:
                pass
            elif row_num > 100:
                break
```